# Save the id only of a row in the SQLite android database

Tags: php, android, sql, sqlite

My android app is getting & writing data to the server and to the SQlite database.

I am fetching values for `jobaddress.id = 1`from server using a query (below). The values in `SELECT`statement are displaying perfectly in the UI of android app however when I press "Save", instead of values from the server, I need to save the id `1` from the server in the local database without shwoing the id in the UI.

PHP sript (query only) for retrieving data from server:

```
$tsql = "SELECT     tbl_manufacturers.manufacturers_name, tbl_appliances_models.appliances_models_name, tbl_appliances.appliances_serial, tbl_appliances.appliances_id, jobaddress.id
        FROM        jobaddress INNER JOIN
                  tbl_appliances ON jobaddress.id = tbl_appliances.appliances_jobaddress_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  tbl_appliances_models INNER JOIN
                  tbl_manufacturers ON tbl_appliances_models.appliances_models_manufacturers_id = tbl_manufacturers.manufacturers_id ON 
                  tbl_appliances.appliances_models_id = tbl_appliances_models.appliances_models_id
        WHERE     (tbl_appliances.appliances_companies_id = 1) AND (jobaddress.id = 1)";
```

Showing data using JSON Parser:

```
public void getJobAddress() 
{
    String result = null;
    InputStream isr = null;
    try
    {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://datanetbeta.multi-trade.co.uk/tablet/getJobAddress.php");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    isr = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Log_tag", "Error in hhtp connection " + e.toString());

    }

    //convert Response to string
    try
    {
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"UTF-8"), 8);
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         String line = null;
         while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
         {

             sb.append(line + "\n");
         }

         isr.close();
         result = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

try
    {

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
             s = json.getString("address1");
             t = json.getString("address2");
             u = json.getString("postcode");
        }

        tvJbAddrs1.setText(s);
        if(t == null)
        {
            tvJbAddrs2.setText("");
        }
        else
        {
            tvJbAddrs2.setText(t);
        }

        tvJbPostcode.setText(u);


    }


catch (Exception e)

{
Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString()); 

}

} //getJobAddress() ends
```

Comment: How are you showing the data, please provide more code.

Comment: Please see now. I  have updated and showing code using JSON Parser

Comment: What does the JSON parser have to do with this? What exactly is your problem with saving? Just insert the ID into the DB table.